# Laravel Valet share - Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused

Tags: laravel, ngrok, laravel-valet, valet

I have Valet setup and running fine on a Laravel project. I can visit mysite.test and the project loads as it should. However, when I run the command *valet share* I get a "Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused" error.

I've tried updating composer, updating homebrew and re-installed valet but the error message still persists. If I run brew services list the following services are all showing as running;

```
dnsmasq   started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
mysql@5.7 started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist
nginx     started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php       started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
```

I don't believe that Apache is running. I get the following error when I try to stop that service;

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service
```

The full error I receive after running valet share is below.

```
ERROR:  Tunnel 'command_line' specifies invalid address 'Sites.
ERROR:  Warning: Class 'Tightenco\Collect\Support\Debug\Dumper' not found in /Users/darren/.composer/vendor/tightenco/collect/src/Collect/Support/alias.php on line 18
ERROR:  
ERROR:  Warning: Class 'Tightenco\Collect\Support\Debug\HtmlDumper' not found in /Users/darren/.composer/vendor/tightenco/collect/src/Collect/Support/alias.php on line 18
ERROR:  test:80': too many colons in address Sites.
ERROR:  Warning: Class 'Tightenco\Collect\Support\Debug\Dumper' not found in /Users/darren/.composer/vendor/tightenco/collect/src/Collect/Support/alias.php on line 18
ERROR:  
ERROR:  Warning: Class 'Tightenco\Collect\Support\Debug\HtmlDumper' not found in /Users/darren/.composer/vendor/tightenco/collect/src/Collect/Support/alias.php on line 18
ERROR:  test:80
Darrens-MacBook-Pro:Sites darren$ Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused

In Request.php line 1028:

  Unable to connect to "http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels": 7 Failed to conne  
  ct to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused                                


fetch-share-url
```

I believe that the PHP class warning is unrelated. Any help in trying to solve this would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Running sudo brew services start --all to make sure all services have indeed started results in the following error;

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist: service already loaded
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist` exited with 133.
```

Answer (score 9):

After hours of debugging this finally solved the issue. Specifically 'symfony/polyfill-php72', 'symfony/var-dumper', 'tightenco/collect' updated during this process so the issue must have been with one of these packages. Every other package was loaded from the cache.

`composer global remove laravel/valet`

`composer self-update`

`composer global require laravel/valet`

`valet install`

`valet restart`

Comment: This worked, here's a one liner `composer global remove laravel/valet && composer self-update && composer global require laravel/valet && valet install && valet restart`

Answer (score 4):

Found another solution:

```
brew install ngrok
cd ~/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/bin
./ngrok authtoken [yourtoken]
cd [back to your laravel proj]
valet share
```

Source and props to mgilberties: https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/837